# Sidebar "Wrapper" Plugin/Widget?

Tags: plugins

I'm coming from a Joomla background and I'm setting up a Wordpress installation for a friend's Shoutcast station. I would have done the setup in Joomla, as I'm more familiar with it, but I wanted to be able to hand administration of the WP install over to my friend once it's going, and I feel Joomla is a bit over her head.

We're using the [shout-stream](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/shout-stream/) plugin for providing a sidebar stream player. We don't care for the stats display of shout-stream, so I was attempting to use a custom PHP  **what's playing now** script I wrote for another station page I did in Joomla. Joomla has a component/plugin that can encapsulate a PHP script and display it in the sidebar.

### My question is:

Is there a similar plugin for Wordpress?

I searched the plugin repository and found one which, at first glance, looked like it might work **(wp-wrapper)**, but further checking indicates it has to be used only on a post or a page. We want the PHP script to run/display in the sidebar. Is there such a plugin for WP or am I stuck going back to Joomla?

Thanks
Dave

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [WordPress widget API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API) to create a custom widget containing your PHP script.

Very simple example:

```
class shoutcast_widget extends WP_Widget {
    function shoutcast_widget() {
    $widget_ops = array(
        'description' => 'Describe your widget here'
    );
        parent::WP_Widget(false, 'Name Your Widget Here', $widget_ops );  
    }   
    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract( $args );
        extract( $instance );
        echo $before_widget; ?>
            <h3 class="widget_title">Your Widget Title</h3>
        <?php

        // Your Custom PHP Script Here That outputs the display
        echo $after_widget;
    }
}
    register_widget( 'shoutcast_widget' );
```

Comment: Thank you.. Will look into the api. I've never done any plugin programming on WP (or Joomla), but can probably figure it out..